# scanf isn't executing on every loop iteration

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, scanf, strcmp

I am writing a program for fun (not for school), and am having a hard time figuring out why the `scanf` function isn't executing on every iteration of my loop - I've toyed with both 'for' loops and 'while' loops.

I know that depending on how I write the `scanf` function (i.e. `scanf("%s", &variablename);` VS `scanf("%99[^\n]s", &variablename);`) makes a difference, but I have tried everything and I'm desperate!

When I do a `printf` check on my input from the `scanf`, on every iteration it is only intaking one string per iteration, so if I enter two words in my first input, then it takes two iterations to process - one word per.  Here is the segment of code I'm describing:

```
int main(void){
    int tries = 0;
    int score = 0;
    char question[100];
    char useranswer[100];
    const char *phrase = {"our favorite saying\0"};

    printf("\nQuestion #3 (10 points): What is our secret saying?\n");
        sleep(1);
        tries = 1;

    while (tries<=3){
        printf("YOUR ANSWER:");
        scanf("%s[^\n]", useranswer); 

        if(strncmp(useranswer, phrase, 15) != 0){
            printf ("Nope, try again!\n");
            printf("You have used %d out of 3 tries!\n", tries);
            if (tries == 2){
                printf("Here's your final hint:xxx...\n");
            }
            if (tries == 3){
            printf("You didn't get it. The answer is: our favorite saying!\n");
            }
            tries++;
        }   
        if (strncmp(useranswer, phrase, 15) == 0){
            printf("Damn, you're good.  Well done.\n");
            score += 10;
            break;
        }
    }
```

The output of this code is:

```
Question #3 (10 points): What is our secret saying?
YOUR ANSWER:our favorite saying
Nope, try again!
You have used 1 out of 3 tries!
YOUR ANSWER:Nope, try again!
You have used 2 out of 3 tries!
Here's your final hint:xxx...
YOUR ANSWER:Nope, try again!
You have used 3 out of 3 tries!
You didn't get it. The answer is: our favorite saying!
```

(It only allowed me to input once, and I typed "our favorite saying".)

Comment: `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", useranswer); `

Comment: The `[...]` isn't an add-on for the `s` specifier... it's a different format specifier on its own.  `%s` reads the next string of non-whitespace characters, and `%[^\n]` (*not* `%s[^\n]`) reads a string of any chars except `\n` -- so the code you have just reads each word one at a time (one per loop).

Comment: `"%s[^\n]"` is not a valid `scanf()` format.  Suggest using `fgets(useranser, sizeof useranswer, stdin)` instead.

Comment: @chux Why is it not valid?

Comment: @immibis  Ahhh yes `"%s[^\n]"` _is_ valid, but certainly not useful nor certainly not what OP hoped for.  `"%s[^\n]"` Would 1a) scan for white-space - throw them away, 1b) scan for non-white-space - save result in `useranswer`, possible over filling it, 1c) encounter an EOF or  white-space and put that back into `stdin` 2) scan and attempt to match `[` with the previous whitespace and fail, ending the scan.  Good catch.

Comment: `scanf` is behaving as described by the manual... hmmm, who'd have thought?! I can't understand the manual, though, so I'll keep focusing on learning the other parts of C and come back to learn about `scanf` once I've learnt those.

Comment: `int x = scanf("%99[^\n]", useranswer);` This first operation might cause `scanf` to return so it can't be merged with the discarding operation: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` the former reading and discarding any excess characters beyond the 99 up to `'\n'` and the latter reading and discarding the newline itself. Again, these two operations cannot be merged into one `scanf` invocation because the left-most operations might cause failure meaning the operations following don't execute. BE CAREFUL with `scanf`! Knowledge is power, and it comes from the manpages in this case...

Comment: Also, following on from that example you'd want to write some logic using `x`... the manual section for `scanf` will tell you, in this case `x` can be `EOF`, `0` or `1` and you'll likely only want to use `useranswer` when `x` is `1` because the others correspond to read errors, end of file and empty fields.

Comment: Thank you everybody, @BLUEPIXY 's solution worked... Much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the logic to follow @Bob suggestions as well, thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

In comments you could find why your format specifier in `scanf` doesn't work.

An alternative is to use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead, maybe in an helper function which takes care of some of the corner cases that can arise while reading user input:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *read_line( char *buf, size_t n, FILE *pfin )
{
    ssize_t length = 0;
    int ch;

    if ( !buf || n == 0 )
        return NULL;
    /*  Consume trailing control characters, like '\0','\n', '\r', '\f'...
        but also '\t'. Note that ' ' is not skipped. */
    while ( (ch = fgetc(pfin)) != EOF  &&  iscntrl(ch) ) { }
    if ( ch == EOF )
        return NULL;
    /*  At least one char is printable  */
    *buf = ch;
    ++length;

    /*  Read from file till a newline or up to n-2 chars. The remaining chars
        are left in the stream buffer. Return NULL if no char is read.      */
    if ( fgets(buf + 1, n - 1, pfin) )
    {
        /*  Trim the string to the first control character                  */
        while ( !iscntrl(buf[length]) ) 
        {
            ++length;
        }
        buf[length] = '\0';       
    }
    return buf;
}
```

I'd change the following logic too. OP uses `strncmp(useranswer, phrase, 15)` multiple times, but that magic number `15` is lower then `phrase`'s size so it ends up comparing only a substring.

```
while ( tries <= 3 ) {
    printf("YOUR ANSWER:");
    if ( !read_line(useranswer, sizeof useranswer, stdin) ) {
        printf("Error: Unexpected end of input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( strcmp(useranswer, phrase) == 0 ) {
        printf("Damn, you're good.  Well done.\n");
        score += 10;
        break;
    } else {
        printf ("Nope, try again!\n");
        printf("You have used %d out of 3 tries!\n", tries);
        if (tries == 2) {
            printf("Here's your final hint:xxx...\n");
        }
        if (tries == 3) {
            printf("You didn't get it. The answer is: our favorite saying!\n");
        }
        tries++;
    }
}
```

---

As a final note, I found OP declaration of `phrase` a bit weird (maybe a typo):

```
const char *phrase = {"our favorite saying\0"};
//            string literals are already ^^ null terminated...
```

While we can use a simple array declaration, like:

```
const char phrase[] = "our favorite saying";
```

Consider also what values `sizeof phrase` returns in those two different cases.

---

Thanks to **@chux** for all the valuable hints and the interesting links provided:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/4944425  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/4944425  
And to **@Dmitri** for having pointed out in his comment that once we are sure that both the strings are null terminated, we can use `strcmp` instead of `strncmp`.

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359  or http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2410359 to remove the potential `'\n'`.  `if ( useranswer[lstr - 1] == '\n')` is not safe.

Comment: @Dmitri if the user enters a longer string, the first part of the condition `lstr == strlen(phrase)` will be false. I followed OP's use of `strncmp` but note that he used `15` as a magic number.

Comment: @chux yes I didn't check for empty lines, my bad.

Comment: ok... but why not just use `strcmp()`, which won't indicate a match when the lengths differ anyway?  Not sure why one would prefer `strncmp()` unless he needs to match on only part of the string..

Comment: @dmitri In this case both strings are well formed (as far as I can tell following the logic of the code) so it wouldn't be necessary to limit the comparison. As I said, I only used the same function used by OP trying to point out his error (the use of fixed and arbitrary number), but again, I agree it isn't necessary.

Comment: Detail: When reading an "empty line", `useranswer[0]` will have `'\n'` in it and `lstr == 1`.  For `useranswer[0]` to have `'\0'` in it occurs when the first text character read is a null character.  This uncommon event is a hacker exploit.